# Monitoring mongoDB in the cluster

Tags: python, mongodb, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor and analyze the results of sharded MongoDB instance in the cluster. There's a nice monitoring tool provided by mongo- MMS. However, I need to analyze and plot CPU/Disk IO, shard load graphs on my own. The question: is it possible to get data from MMS (i.e. timestamps,opcoutns, CPU utilization) in CVS or something that would be possible to load in R/Python?

Comment: yes, just run the command db.serverStatus() that's where all the numbers come from.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Got it! Thank you. It was exactly what I've looked for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own tool, although I highly doubt that it will be better then MMS. As Asya suggested, you can use `db.serverStatus()` to read some of the data. You can check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/) for more commands and tools for collecting data.

You can do a dirty test with some other parameters from [mongostats](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#fields) command. Also the fields it output are slightly different from what you put in the brackets, but you try to build it easy. All you need is just redirect the output from this command to a text file.

In window you will do this with `mongostat > stats.txt` and if I remember this correctly in linux `mongostat stats.txt`. Then just parse the file with R/python and plot whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you @Salvador_Dali. I now it won't be better than MMS, I need to analyze data by my self. db.serverStatus it was something that I looked for. Thanks!